# Dynamic SQL Query in Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

I have a function

```
public void executeMyQuery(Connection con) {
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE ID = ?");
    ps.setInt(1, 7);
    ps.executeQuery();
}
```

if i will run this it will work fine. But I want to do like this.

1. if I will setInt it should include WHERE clause. (returns matched
   row)
2. if I don't setInt it should exclude WHERE clause. (returns whole table)

Or is there is any way to dynamically remove or modify the string after WHERE Clause.

Comment: `mysql` or `sql-server`? Pick (the right) one...

Comment: As far as 'it will work fine' is concerned - no, it will not. You never close the PreparedStatement.

Comment: Actually what you want are not only two SQLs  as suggested by others but two methods, something like findAll and findOneById.

Comment: You shouldn't even try to do this. You either want to select one row or you want to select all rows. That's determined by what **your** intention is, not by whether you call `setInt()` or not. You should have 2 mehods, one which requires an `int` parameter and one that doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to build your query dynamically, at the beginning of the method check whether `id` is `null` or equal `0`. To make it easier you can use trick in where clause with `1=1` so where clause can be included all the time in the query.

```
public void executeMyQuery( Connection con, Integer id) {
String query = "SELECT *FROM STUDENT WHERE 1=1";
if(id != null){
   query += "AND ID = ?";
}
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);

if(id != null){
   ps.setInt(1, id);
}
ps.executeQuery();}
```

Comment: +1 for 1=1.. solving a slightly different problem; but that was the last piece I was grappling with; how to consistently add n amount of operators.

Answer (score 4):

#### Disadvantages of using string based SQL for dynamic SQL

Other answers have shown how to achieve dynamic SQL using string based JDBC usage. There are many disadvantages to building SQL strings dynamically using string concatenation, including:

- High risk of SQL injection if you accidentally concatenate user input to your SQL queries
- Difficult to avoid syntax errors in non-trivial cases, when dynamic SQL gets more complex

Also, when you're using plain JDBC (which only supports indexed bind variables), rather than some utility such as Spring [JdbcTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html), [MyBatis](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/), [jOOQ](https://blog.jooq.org/2020/03/05/using-java-13-text-blocks-for-plain-sql-with-jooq/), etc. you will have to manually match `?` placeholders with their corresponding indexes, which is another subtle source of errors.

#### Using a query builder

At some point, when you implement dynamic SQL queries more often, query builders will definitely help. The most popular ones are:

- [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org) (for dynamic SQL querying)
- [JPA Criteria Query](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjitv.html) (for dynamic JPAL querying)

There are many other options that are more or less well maintained. For very trivial cases (like the one in your question), you can also build your own simple predicate builder.

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ.

Answer (score 0):

ifNull/Coalesce work nicely for this, if you pass a null, it will select where the field equals itself.

```
SELECT * 
FROM STUDENT 
WHERE 1 = 1
and ID = ifNull(:ID, ID)
```

I'd also suggest something other than using ? for your variables, fine when you a couple but as you get a ton of them, difficult to keep track or modify.  I've found https://github.com/dejlek/jlib/blob/master/src/main/java/com/areen/jlib/sql/NamedParameterStatement.java pretty easy, made a few modifications to fit my particular needs but SQL is much easier to read and doing substitutions in intellij db console are much easier when developing the SQL.

Answer (score -1):

You can have two PreparedStatements defined in your program - one without the `WHERE ID = ?` clause, and another one with it.

Moreover, you are supposed to keep your `PreparedStatements` and re-use, so you better store them as a field, etc.

And then, when needing to get the data - call either the first prepared statement, or the second one.

Comment: I would use two `String` but one `PreparedStatement`, there is no need to create two if one will not be used ;)

Answer (score -3):

Michael Dz is close to the solution in his answer, but there is a problem in the code : he calls setInt on a non existing preparedStatement.

Try something like this :

```
public void executeMyQuery( Connection con, int Id) {
    StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer();
    sql.append("Select * FROM STUDENT");
    if(Id > -1) {
        sql.append(" Where ID = ?");
    }
    preparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
    if(ID > -1) {
        ps.setInt(1, Id);
    }
    ps.executeQuery();   // You might want to catch the result of the query as well
}
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: You are not supposed to recreate `PreparedStatements` with every call.

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki: Caching such objects is very difficult. More sophisticated JDBC drivers (e.g. ojdbc) will ship with a built in prepared statement cache, which takes care of most of the prepare overhead if the same statement is prepared several times per connection.